# How to pass attributes in chef-client without JSON file?

Tags: chef-infra

I know we can pass node attributes in chef-{client/solo} with --json-attributes(-j) flag.
This flag always expect a JSON file as input. Is their any method I can directly pass the attributes as JSON objects.

I tried doing it. For eg:

```
chef-client -j {"attr":"value"}
```

But it ends up with a failure message as:

```
FATAL: I cannot find {"attr":"value"}
```

As it expects a JSON file. 
I need to pass JSON objects as in our env I can't create a json file. I don't want to use attributes/role/environment files as well. Is there any other way to pass the attributes ?

Comment: As a workaround you could try to upload the JSON somewhere else and enter the URL of the JSON. May that works?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you tried piping the JSON to STDIN?

`echo '{"attr":"value"}' | chef-client -j /dev/stdin`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
knife ssh $VM -- chef-client -j '<(echo \{\"attr\":\"value\"\})' --no-fork
```

YMMV